# sorting data that has blanks or gaps

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have data like this:

```
var dataset  = [ 
  { "field1":"val1", "field2":"val2", "field3":"34.11" },
  { "field1":"val4", "field2":"val5", "field4":"2/3/2015" },
  { "field1":"val6", "field2":"val7", "field3": "26.37", "field4":"4/2/2015" }
 ] ;
```

As you see these data is missing "field3" in the second row and missing "field4" in the first row so how I can sort these data using javascript only ? if this wont work is it possible to loop through dataset to enter the missing fields in each row ? as I can not control the incoming data.

I was able to sort the dataset for strings and numbers but only if all rows are present for example this for string columns:

```
dataset.sort(function (a, b) {
  var nameA = a.field1.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.field1.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase

  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
});
```

The desired output is HTML table but I know how to generate this table using Javascript so I just want to be able to sort each column separately asc or desc based on the column value type. for example sorting asc for field3 should be

```
var dataset  = [ 
   { "field1":"val4", "field2":"val5", "field4":"2/3/2015" },      
   { "field1":"val6", "field2":"val7", "field3": "26.37", "field4":"4/2/2015" },      
   { "field1":"val1", "field2":"val2", "field3":"34.11" }     

 ] ;
```

Update:
My code trying to sort based on field3 but I get incorrect sort

```
dataset.sort(function (a, b) {

  var nameA = Number(a.field3); 
  var nameB = Number(b.field3); 

  return (nameB - nameA);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how/what you want to sort? What is the desired output?

Comment: I am going to display these data in html table using also Javascript and I want to sort each column asc or desc but separately

Comment: Update the question with the desired output. How does `dataset` should look like **after** the sorting

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Do you understand that `B < A` is **exactly** the same as `A > B`?

Comment: I don't see the desired output in the updated question.

Comment: @PM77-1 corrected.

Comment: @Dekel you mean the html output ?

Comment: if you try to access field3 you'll get an error you can avoid that by doing something like `var nameA = a.field3 && a.field3.toUpperCase();`

Comment: No, I mean that you want to sort the `dataset` array, so after the sorting you want a sorted array. How is this sorted array look like?

Comment: Your `dataset` is an array of objects.  Show us the sorted version of this array.

Comment: I posted example how I want it to be sorted based on field3 ascending

Comment: So if you don't have `field3` - the object that don't have it should go first?

Comment: yes as a blank or empty value this is how I get the data

Comment: I didn't ask how you get, I asked what the sorting function should do.

Comment: for field3 sort the numbers ascending or descending if the field does not exists then treat it as empty value

Comment: What does it mean for a number to treat it as an "empty value"? What's an empty number?

Comment: @melpomene when field3 is not exists then this mean empty or no value

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. What should the sorting function do with an empty field? You said "treat it as empty value" but that's not an answer.

Comment: @melpomene ok sorted first in ascending case

Comment: OK. Have you tried writing code to do that? What problems did you run into?

Comment: Added an answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
dataset.sort(function (a, b) {

  var nameA = Number(a.field3)||0; //if value is NaN use 0
  var nameB = Number(b.field3)||0; //if value is NaN use 0

  return (nameA - nameB); //wrong order (nameB - nameA) returns greatest to least
});
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "val4",
    "field2": "val5",
    "field4": "2/3/2015"
  },
  {
    "field1": "val6",
    "field2": "val7",
    "field3": "26.37",
    "field4": "4/2/2015"
  },
  {
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "field3": "34.11"
  }
]
```

Field 4:

```
dataset.sort(function (a, b) {
  var nameA = (new Date(a.field4)); 
   if ( isNaN( nameA.getTime() ) ) {  //checks if date is invalid
    nameA = -10e15;
  }
  var nameB = (new Date(b.field4)); 
 if ( isNaN( nameB.getTime() ) ) {  
    nameB = -10e15;
  }
  return (nameA - nameB); 
});
```

Dataset In:

```
var dataset  = [ 
   { "field1":"val4", "field2":"val5", "field4":"2/3/2015" },      
   { "field1":"val6", "field2":"val7", "field3": "26.37", "field4":"4/2/2015" },      
   { "field1":"val1", "field2":"val2", "field3":"34.11" },       
   { "field1":"val1", "field2":"val2", "field3":"34.11", "field4":"4/1/2003" }     
 ] ;
```

Dataset Out:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "field3": "34.11"
  },
  {
    "field1": "val1",
    "field2": "val2",
    "field3": "34.11",
    "field4": "4/1/2003"
  },
  {
    "field1": "val4",
    "field2": "val5",
    "field4": "2/3/2015"
  },
  {
    "field1": "val6",
    "field2": "val7",
    "field3": "26.37",
    "field4": "4/2/2015"
  }
]
```

Comment: This code is not generic. If you have more missing fields (and not only field3) this code will not work.

Comment: please help me how I do the same for field4 the date type ?

Comment: The answer was edited to show how to do it for field4. I will look into making a generic version of this.

Comment: Thanks Steven but this did not work for field4 there are empty values between the rows, they are not sorted first or last. if you populate more random data you will get my result.

Comment: Updated answer with the correct solution for field 4.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get empty values between rows ! is there any information I should provide to you ?

Comment: Can you please show me the dataset that is causing the issue?

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure the updated answer works, perhaps you pasted the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general sorting function.

If you have a missing field - this field gets first. Otherwise - the order will be based on the `localeCompare` of the values of the same fields.

```js
var dataset  = [ 
  { "field1":"val1", "field2":"val2", "field3":"34.11" },
  { "field1":"val4", "field2":"val5", "field4":"2/3/2015" },
  { "field1":"val6", "field2":"val7", "field3": "26.37", "field4":"4/2/2015" }
 ] ;

dataset.sort(function (a, b) {
  aFields = Object.keys(a).sort()
  bFields = Object.keys(b).sort()
  i = 0;
  if (aFields[i] == bFields[i]) {
    if (a[aFields[i]].localeCompare(b[bFields[i]]) == 0) {
      i++;
    } else {
      return a[aFields[i]].localeCompare(b[bFields[i]]);
    }
  } else {
    return bFields[i].localeCompare(aFields[i]);
  }
});

console.log(dataset)
```

Comment: I believe this does not match his or her expected output.

Comment: He said that if a field is missing it should be considered as empty == first, and this is exactly what happen here.

Comment: Thanks but I need sorting for each column separated so the code posted by Steven Tang work perfectly for field3