# How to sort date data when there are blanks

Tags: javascript, sorting

I wrote this code to sort date field `fdate` ascending or descending but I get blank values for this sort what I need is how to put all blank records at the top if I sort in ascending order or how I put these blank records at the end when I sort in descending order ?

```js
var dataset = [{
  "field1": "dfg34r",
  "field2": "32.24"
}, {
  "field1": "d3f32dg",
  "field2": "32.52",
  "fdate": "3/2/2015"
}, {
  "field1": "fdbhjjts",
  "fdate": "7/4/2015"
}, {
  "field1": "dfg4r",
  "field2": "2.24"
}, {
  "field1": "fgsdfwe",
  "fdate": "3/1/2015"
}];

dataset.sort(function(a, b) {
      var x = new Date(a.fdate);
      var y = new Date(b.fdate);
      return x.valueOf() - y.valueOf();
    });

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dataset);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You already asked this exact question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309228/sorting-data-that-has-blanks-or-gaps

Comment: @Dekel I dont know what to do, in this sample data the sort work but in actual data it does not !!

Comment: This really isn't a reason for opening the exact same question every day. If you want to get more attention you get set a bounty on your question (I think the problem is that the question isn't clear enough, but maybe it's only me).

Comment: @Dekel this time I face the problem for date fields not any other types

Answer (score 1):

A more universal solution is to check if a property is missing, and return `1` or `-1` to determine the sort order. This works regardless of the data type.

I've added the `factor` option, that you can change to determine ascending / descending.

```js
var dataset = [{"field1":"dfg34r","field2":"32.24"},{"field1":"d3f32dg","field2":"32.52","fdate":"3/2/2015"},{"field1":"fdbhjjts","fdate":"7/4/2015"},{"field1":"dfg4r","field2":"2.24"},{"field1":"fgsdfwe","fdate":"3/1/2015"}];

var factor = 1; // change to -1 for descending

dataset.sort(function(a, b) {
  // if prop a doesn't exist
  if (!a.fdate) {
    return factor * -1;
  }

  // if prop b doesn't exist
  if (!b.fdate) {
    return factor * 1;
  }

  return factor * (new Date(a.fdate) - new Date(b.fdate));
});

console.log(dataset);
```

**Original solution**

If `fdate` doesn't exist use `0` instead. `new Date(0)` is the 1st date in unix time - Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern Europe Standard Time).

```js
var dataset = [{"field1":"dfg34r","field2":"32.24"},{"field1":"d3f32dg","field2":"32.52","fdate":"3/2/2015"},{"field1":"fdbhjjts","fdate":"7/4/2015"},{"field1":"dfg4r","field2":"2.24"},{"field1":"fgsdfwe","fdate":"3/1/2015"}];

dataset.sort(function(a, b) {
  var x = new Date(a.fdate || 0);
  var y = new Date(b.fdate || 0);
  return x.valueOf() - y.valueOf();
});

console.log(dataset);
```

Comment: This will break if fdate is before 01/01/1970.

Comment: this is really strange, in this sample data the sort work but in actual data I get incorrect sort !!

Comment: @OriDrori thanks this eliminate gaps or empty records but the sort itself is not correct see image with actual data for sorting in descending order http://imgur.com/a/8KcQr

Comment: @Wel - your dates are in the wrong format - try this in your console - `new Date('23/4/2015');`. Change this into `new Date('4/23/2015');`, and it will work.

Comment: is there a way to reformat the date to be month/day/year as I can not change the data coming to me

Comment: You can do this easily using [`datejs`](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) with `Date.parseExact("23/4/2004", "d/M/yyyy");`